# My $_POST variables change into NULL when form takes action

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am making HTML table form in `ticketqueue.php` So when `Assign me` submit button is clicked it takes user to `ticketinfo.php` there i use $_POST to take row value into some variables. Table code is as the following:

```
//ticketqueue.php
echo "<form method='post' action='ticketinfo.php'>
              <tr id='myrow'>
                <td><input name='id' value='$id' readonly></td>
                <td><input name='subject' value='$subject' readonly></td>
                <td><input name='department' value='$department' readonly></td>
                <td><input name='category' value='$categoryview' readonly></td>
                <td>$status</td>
                <td><input type='submit' name='assign' value='Assign me'></td>
                <td><input type='hidden' name='ticketdepart' value='$departmentID' readonly></td>
              </tr>
            </form>";
```

Now in the other page `ticketinfo.php` i have another form with submit buttons so that user can reply or close the ticket. When i click any of these buttons the $_POST variables like `$ticketdepart` change into NULL. Code is as follows:

```
//ticketinfo.php
require_once "config.php";
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
  session_destroy();
  header("location: login.php");
  exit;
  }

//Passing ticket data after its clicked from table
$style = "";
$ticketID = $_POST["id"];
$ticketdepart = $_POST["ticketdepart"];
$userdepart = $_SESSION["userdepartmentID"];
$techID = $_SESSION["myID"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$department = $_POST["department"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];

echo $department;

//Check if technician department is same as the ticket's
if($ticketdepart != $userdepart){
  $style = "style='display:none;'";
  echo "Ticket is not meant for your department";
}else{

  //Extracting ticket data from database
  $query = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE id=:ticketID";
  $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam('ticketID',$ticketID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if($count == 1){
    $technicianID = $row["technicianID"];
    $created_at = $row["created_at"];
    $content = $row["content"];
    $userID = $row["userID"];
    }else{
    echo "Parsing error";
  }

  //Extracting  the ticket user's name from database
  $query2 = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=:userID";
  $stmt2 = $connection->prepare($query2);
  $stmt2->bindParam('userID',$userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt2->execute();
  $count2 = $stmt2->rowCount();
  $row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if($count2 == 1){
    $name = $row2["name"];
    }else {
    echo "Parsing error 2";
  }



  /*Checking whether ticket was assigned or not and
  if it's assigned to another technician*/
  if($technicianID == TRUE && $technicianID != $techID){
    $style = "style='display:none;'";
    //echo "Ticket is not assigned to you";
  }elseif ($technicianID == TRUE && $technicianID == $techID) {
    //echo "It's your ticket";
  }elseif ($technicianID == NULL) {
    $query3 = "UPDATE ticket SET technicianID=:techID, statusID=2 WHERE id=:ticketID";
    $stmt3 = $connection->prepare($query3);
    $stmt3->bindParam('techID',$techID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt3->bindParam('ticketID',$ticketID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if($stmt3->execute()){
      //echo "Ticket just got assigned to you";
    }
  }

  //When technician replies to the ticket
  if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
     if($reply != NULL){
       $reply = $_POST["reply"];
       $query4 = "INSERT INTO comments(ticketID,userID,created_at,content)
       VALUES(:ticketID,:techID,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),:reply)";
       $stmt4 = $connection->prepare($query4);
       $stmt4->bindParam('ticketID',$ticketID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $stmt4->bindParam('userID',$techID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $stmt4->bindParam('reply',$reply, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       if($stmt4->execute()){
         echo "Replied successfully";
       }else{
       echo "You didn't reply to the ticket!";
      }
    }
  }

  //When technician close ticket
  if (isset($_POST["close"])) {
    $query4 = "UPDATE ticket SET statusID=3 WHERE id=:ticketID";
    $stmt4 = $connection->prepare($query4);
    if($stmt4->execute()){
      echo "Ticket just got closed";
    }
  }
}


 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Ticketinfo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="" <?php echo $style; ?>>
       <form method="post" action="">
         <div>
           <label>Sent by:</label>
           <label><?php echo $name; ?></label>
         </div>
         <div>
           <label>Ticket no.:</label>
           <label><?php echo $ticketID; ?></label>
         </div>
         <div>
           <label>Category:</label>
           <label><?php echo $category; ?></label>
         </div>
         <div>
           <label>Department requested:</label>
           <label><?php echo $department; ?></label>
         </div>
         <div>
           <label>Subject:</label>
           <label><?php echo $subject; ?></label>
         </div>
         <div>
           <label>Created at:</label>
           <label><?php echo $created_at; ?></label>
         </div>
         <div id="content">
           <p><?php echo $name.": ".$content; ?></p>
         </div>
         <div>
           <input type="message" name="reply" >
         </div>
         <div>
           <input type="submit" name="send" value="Reply">
         </div>
         <div>
           <input type="submit" name="escalate" value="Escalate ticket">
         </div>
         <div>
           <input type="submit" name="close" value="Close ticket">
         </div>
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: $_POST values will only exist when `ticketinfo.php` is launched from the submit of `ticketqueue.php` They do not stay in existance when you then submit the `ticketinfo.php` form as that form has NO input fields and therefore nothing gets sent in $_POST by that form

Comment: How do i solve this  problem then?

Comment: Didn't we [go through this already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941324/my-html-form-isnt-workingcorrectly-when-i-click-a-button)? If you want to transfer values to the next request, you need to place that data into form elements (in your case, hidden inputs seem the most sensible).

Comment: Well you could place the data you want to keep in <input>'s in the second form. You couldd put the data you want to keep in the session

Comment: @El_Vanja So we did, thought I recognised it from somewhere

Comment: Am sorry @El_Vanja i didn't realize the answer then. i will try it now. am a beginner so thank you for your patience.

Comment: Do i make the hidden inputs in second form POST the values from the  first one then POST these values from second form into  variables? @El_Vanja

Comment: That's the general idea. You fill the `value` attribute of the hidden inputs in the second form with the corresponding variables from `$_POST` (that you got from the first form submission). That way when the second form is submitted, it will repost them.

Comment: So i made hidden inputs with values equal to echoed POST values of first form then i took their values using POST but code now is acting in a different weird manner

Comment: If  you could help me by typing some code changes according to my code it might be easier for me.

Comment: When the control moves from one web page to the next in PHP, _all_ data is lost.  If you want to hang onto anything, you need to take action -- passing args in the url, cookies, 'session'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using JavaScript in the first form as to take ticket `id` from first cell in the table when its row is clicked and pass its value into a hidden HTML input in the form and then taking that value by using $_POST into a $_SESSION variable as to query ticket data in the next page. Code in the first form:

```
echo "<tr>
              <td>$id</td>
              <td>$subject</td>
              <td>$department</td>
              <td>$categoryview</td>
              <td>$status</td>
              <td><input type='submit' name='assign' value='Claim'></td>
            </tr>";

echo "</table>
  <input type='hidden' id='valueID' name='ticketID'>
  <input type='hidden' id='valuedepart' name='ticketdepart'>
  </form>
  <script>
    var table = document.getElementById('table'),rIndex;
    for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++){
        table.rows[i].onclick = function()
        {
          rIndex = this.rowIndex;
          document.getElementById('valueID').value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
          document.getElementById('valuedepart').value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
        }
    }
  </script>
  </body>";
```

PHP code which i used to pass the values i want into $_SESSION variables:

```
if(isset($_POST["assign"])){
  $_SESSION["ticketID"] = $_POST["ticketID"];
  $_SESSION["ticketdepart"] = $_POST["ticketdepart"];
  header("location: ticketinfo.php");
  exit;
}
```